# A Doubt from Probability on Trees and Networks

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, percolation

I am working through chapter 8 of the mentioned book by Lyons and Peres. I am having trouble understanding the argument they have used to explain the fact that there can't exist an invariant way to pick a finite number of vertices at random.

I don’t quite understand what does pick a vertex uniformly from the finite set means and how they get an invariant measure on the singletons. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yzkyr.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have done that .